# How do I group matching items only if they are next to each other

Tags: javascript

Im trying to look over an array and create an array where items that match on a certain property and are next to each other are grouped:

For example:

```
  const allEvents =  [{type: "A"}, {type: "B"}, {type: "B"}, {type: "C"}, {type: "A"}, {type: "A"}, {type: "C"}, {type: "A"}]

  const result = [[{type: "A"}], [{type: "B"},{type: "B"}], [{type: "C"}], [{type: "A"},{type: "A"}], [{type: "C"}],[{type: "A"}]]
```

Trying something like this:

```
  const groupedEvents = [];
  let index = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < allEvents.length; index += 1) {
    const element = allEvents[index];

    const group = [element];

    while (index < allEvents.length && allEvents[index + 1]) {
      const nextEvent = allEvents[index + 1];
      const isUpdateType = updates.includes(nextEvent.type);
      const isSameUser = element.adminUser === nextEvent.adminUser;

      if (isUpdateType && isSameUser) {
        index += 1;
        group.push(nextEvent);
      } else {
        groupedEvents.push(group);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

The above code is ignoring the last item however likely because `&& allEvents[index + 1]`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't often recommend `reduce` but this might be an exception (depends what you mean by "efficient" though).

Comment: At this point i'd opt for at least working. Right now this nested loop skips the last item

Comment: I think you have your answer now, but one thing I was wondering about as I made my own attempt was what to do if you had: `[{adminUser: "A"}, {adminUser: "A", type: 'update'}]`; should it be `[[{adminUser: "A"}], [{adminUser: "A", type: 'update'}]]` or `[[{adminUser: "A"}, {adminUser: "A", type: 'update'}]]`?

Comment: Hey Ben, I think the first one is correct, if the types don't match, they would not be grouped. Same if the type is missing, it should be it's own group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like should work:

```js
const allEvents =  [{type: "A"}, {type: "B"}, {type: "B"}, {type: "C"}, {type: "A"}, {type: "A"}, {type: "C"}, {type: "A"}];

const result = allEvents.reduce((acc, ev) => {
   if ( acc.length > 0 && acc[acc.length - 1][0].type === ev.type) {
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(ev);
   } else {
      acc.push([ev]);
   }
   return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Trying to translate the above to your specific case would result in:

```
const groupedEvents = allEvents.reduce((acc, ev) => {
   if (acc.length > 0 && 
        updates.includes(ev.type) && 
        ev.adminUser === acc[acc.length - 1][0].adminUser) {
      acc[acc.length - 1].push(ev);
   } else {
      acc.push([ev]);
   }
   return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const allEvents = [{adminUser: "A", type: 'update'}, {adminUser: "B", type: 'update'}, {adminUser: "B", type: 'update'}, {adminUser: "C"}, {adminUser: "A"}, {adminUser: "A", type: 'update'}, {adminUser: "C"}, {adminUser: "A"}]

const updates = ['update'];

const group_by = fn => array => array.reduce(
    (acc, v, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => 
      last && fn(v, last) ? acc[acc.length - 1].push(v) && acc : acc.concat([[v]]),
    []
  );

const group_by_admin_and_type = group_by(
  (value, last) => last.adminUser === value.adminUser && updates.includes(value.type) && updates.includes(last.type)
);

console.log(group_by_admin_and_type(allEvents));
```